# ¿Como editar un campo que esta localizado en el localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: Mi problema es sencillo, cree un documento HTML/Javascript donde puedes escribir en 4 campos donde luego aparecen en una tabla utilizando el "local storage" del navegador, y todo va bien. Bueno justamente mis compañeros me dijeron que necesito implementar una manera de poder editar los campos 1 por 1, ósea cuando por ejemplo]

No podre exactamente poner el código ya que esta en otro ordenador sin internet y en otro sistema operativo (Ubuntu).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```javascript
let obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("myKey"))[0];

let propName = prompt("Enter the name of the property you want to edit:");

let newValue = prompt("Enter the new value for " + propName + ":");

obj[propName] = newValue;

localStorage.setItem("myKey", JSON.stringify([obj]));

alert("Value updated successfully!");
```

Comment: Las respuestas que tienen solo código tienden a ser consideradas de mala calidad. Por favor, tomate el tiempo de explicar al AP cómo esto resuelve su problema. Por otro lado, el que uses una cuenta distinta para responder a tu propia pregunta se considera un abuso del sistema. Siempre puedes responder a tu propia pregunta utilizando la misma cuenta y aceptarla. Eso no te dará reputación. La reputación siempre viene de otros miembros de la comunidad. Te invito a leer [ask].

Comment: @Mateo está bien __AP__: _Autor/a de la Publicación_. __OP__ es en inglés: _Original Poster_.